# Magento 2 : How to invoke soap wsdl request for magento2 in Postman?

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v1

When i am giving url in postman using get method.

http://127.0.0.1/magento/2.1/soap/default?wsdl&services=taxTaxRateRepositoryV1

then it showing **Consumer is not authorized to access %resources**
is there anything which i have to done to see core soap api's of Magento.

Answer (score 1):

you can't access this resources directly since it is a protected with self-resources. You Can do this by making the resources to "anonymous" in webapi.xml so that you can view it's WSDL structure clearly.